# How to have a list of long values in a DTO

Tags: java, spring

In my Spring boot application, I use DTOs to cast the incoming request body to a class:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addUser(@RequestBody UserDto userDto, Principal principal) throws IOException {
    //...
}
```

Among different attributes of this DTO class, there's a list of long values:

```
public class UserDto implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private List<Long> userIds;

    public void setUserIds(List<Long> userIds) {
       this.userIds = userIds;
    }
}
```

I'm writing a end to end test which tests `addUser` endpoint. But it throws 500 error code before getting to the first line of code in the `addUser` method. I digged into the code and tried different things, and I found out that this works:

```
    public void setUserIds(Object userIds) {
       System.out.println(userIds); // this outputs [12,3,122,44] 
    }
```

I want to know how should I handle a method that sets a list of values for a DTO object.

**Edit 1**

I tried `System.out.println(userIds.getClass())` and it returns `String`

Comment: Which is the real type of `users`? Is it a string containing `[1,2,3]`? If yes, you need to extract all numbers, you can't just cast.

Comment: Please show us a minimal viable example. Where does `users` came from?

Comment: @Chris311 I mentioned in the question: it's part of a DTO class, and it comes from Spring rest controller request body.

Comment: @BackSlash it's passed in as a json value, so basically it's a string, but originally (from the client point of view) it was an array of long values.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh please show us how you are reading the JSON, and tell us which library it is

Comment: @BackSlash I edited the question and I hope it's clear now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use below technique if you are using Java 8 otherwise you need to cast them manually:

If `users` is kind of `String` array which you have converted from `user Object`.

```
long[] longArray = Arrays.stream(users).mapToLong(Long::longValue).toArray();
```

Note: take care of `NumberFormatException`

Comment: `users` is an object, not an array. Why should stream take in an object ? the whole point is to cast an object to an array, but you assumed `users` is an array.

Comment: @ArianHosseinzadeh But that's what you are suggesting with `[1,2,3]` in your question. If it's a `String`, you cannot **cast** it to an array. Split it, then parse it -- but that's not **casting**.

Comment: I edited the question, I think it should be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

In java "Object" class is a cosmic class because [every class is subclass of "Object" class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/objectclass.html). For error detection, you should check parameter "users" in your "setUser" method. Check what class is passing to user parameter. it's simple to do, there is a line to check:

```
System.out.println(users.getClass());
```

it'll show the class of the "users" parameter. If resulted class is "String" and it have numeric format (ex: "123.45"), you can directly cast it to numeric, for example to "Double" :

```
Double.parseDouble("123.45");
```

But, if resulted class from checking is String with format, i often say it "feedback format" because if you do Array.toString() you'll get same format, for example: "[12, 3.4, 5]", it more tricky to extract the number. You can parse the String using [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html) and cast every extracted number to Integer/Floating number class. Every suggestion i've made here is different from your context, but on the same analogous.

Comment: I edited the question, I think it should be clearer now.